# MySQL 5.7.24 -- The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Tags: mysql, passwords, native

I'm using this software:

```
MAMP     4.2
MySQL    5.7.24  <-- PLEASE NOTE
PHP      7.4.1
Windows  10
```

This PHP code ...

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;';
try {
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'root');
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e;
}
```

... generates this error:

```
PDOException: PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
```

Repeat: I am NOT using MySQL 8, and I repeat that fact because every article I've found on this topic claims that this error relates to MySQL version 8.

This SQL statement:

```
select user, plugin from mysql.user
```

Gives these results:

```
root            mysql_native_password   
mysql.session   mysql_native_password   
mysql.sys       mysql_native_password
```

I've added this to my.ini:

```
default-authentication-plugin = mysql_native_password
```

And I'm still getting the error after restarting the MySQL server. I've attempted to upgrade to MySQL 8.0 using MAMP's tools, and that doesn't happen. **Is it a PHP PDO issue?**

By the way, since MAMP on Windows 10 ships with MySQL 5.7 -- *I have no idea why* -- and I frequently use MAMP because it's so easy to install and requires virtually no configuration, 'upgrade to MySQL 8.0' isn't really the answer I'm seeking because I presume there is solution that involves tweaking the configuration. If it's the only answer that anyone has, I'll guess I'll ditch MAMP and go with something else.

I welcome your advice.

Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

If u think "Is it a PHP PDO issue?", here is my comment on it,

I'm new to this and working on my first html form to bind with mysql DB tables. I came across (The only proper) PDO tutorialans here is the URL :  https://phpdelusions.net/pdo.

Comment: Naushad, when I mentioned PDO in this context, I meant the way in which PHP and MySQL work together regarding SHA-2 cryptography. The full error message shown above is:

PDOException: PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution**: Windows is no longer a target environment for MAMP, so this is basically my fault for trying to use it on Windows. MAMP is intended for Mac OS X. So I'm switching to XAMPP. --David